# NSArray name from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I need to make some values of NSArray. Every array must have a unique name. I'm generating ID by this code

```
CFUUIDRef newUniqueId = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
NSString * uuidString = (__bridge NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueId);
CFRelease(newUniqueId);
```

Now i want to create array with name of uuidString content. Can i realize it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes you can make it like this

```
CFUUIDRef newUniqueId = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
NSString * uuidString = (__bridge NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueId);
CFRelease(newUniqueId);

NSMutableDictionary myArray=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSArray arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: "Do your initializtation"];
[myArray setObject: arr forKey:uuidString ];
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to stick all the arrays in an NSMutableDictionary. Arrays don't inherently have a "name," but NSDictionary allows you to create associations between strings and objects (such as NSArrays) like you want to do here.